# pgRouting 2.0 slow execution of A star algorithm

Tags: pgrouting, osm2po, astar, dijkstra

Recently, I wanted to test `pgRouting` ver. 2.0. I created the database structure with osm2po and imported UK map from [geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html). The data was imported correctly.

When I execute a sample query in order to find the shortest path with `dijkstra` algorithm I receive the result in ~70 sec. When I do the same with `astar` algorigthm I get the result in over 145 sec. Theoritically, the result of `astar` should be faster than `dijkstra`'s one but it's not.

Queries I execute:

#### Dijkstra

```sql
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost 
    FROM pgr_dijkstra(
        'SELECT id::integer, source::integer, target::integer, cost::double precision AS cost 
             FROM hh_2po_4pgr'::text, 60, 80, false, false);
```

#### Astar

```sql
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost 
FROM pgr_astar(
    'SELECT id AS id, source::integer, target::integer, cost::double precision AS cost, x1, y1, x2, y2 
        FROM hh_2po_4pgr', 60, 80, false, false);
```

I checked the Astar implementation in `pgRouting` and it seems that it uses this heuristic: `(|dx|+|dy|)/2`.

Am I doing something wrong in my queries or there is something wrong with `pgr_astar()` implementation in `pgRouting`?

Comment: Are you sure that (|dx|+|dy|)/2 is the heuristic? This seems strange. What are dx, dy? The heuristic must be added somewhere to the costs before inserted into the PQ.

Comment: I took it straight from: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/blob/master/src/astar/src/astar_boost_wrapper.cpp

lines 71-74 (comment section)

Comment: The heuristic looks very strange.

Comment: So what is your guess? That heuristic is wrong in official implementation of pgRouting?

Comment: looks like a heuristic based on the Manhattan-Distance. If not, the data must be projected somewhere before. Nevertheless, I would have expected a distance calculation. Some Euklidian function or sth. like that.

Comment: both a_star and pgr_dijkstra make calls to the Boost C++ library.  Boost might be better to answer this question.  You can find more information about contacting them here:  http://www.boost.org/community/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have whole europe ? If so, those times  are probably what you can expect. I have experience only from Finnish osm dataset , with that i got under 1 sec constantly without limiting dataset.

Few performance pointer: Double check that you have indexes, if you have not tuned base postgresql.conf to use more memory , do it (defaults are  very very low ). If you really need max performance from database , consider tablespace on RAMDISK. And last but not least limit your data. [Why is any pgr_* routing function taking forever based on OSM data in an pgrouting enabled DB](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69722/why-is-any-pgr-routing-function-taking-forever-based-on-osm-data-in-an-pgrouti/69825#69825) had some converstation about it.

Comment: As I wrote above I imported UK not europe. But the question was not about time of execution of the each query (in meaning that they are executing too long) but rather about why the Astar algorithm is slower than Dijkstra.

Comment: @KamilKubacki If that is your question then I think you need to edit your question to make that clearer.