# Select a subset of a PostGis table

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I'm using a big table imported by a `*.shp` file of the city of San Diego. When I run `pgr_dijkstra` it takes more or less 5000ms, even for small distances. I was thinking, in order to improve performance, how could I select a subset of the table San Diego? And more important, do you think it would improve the performance?

My idea is to, given a starting and ending point, select only an area (a circle, square,...) that contains both starting and ending point (plus an arbitrary margin). Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is common practice to speedup queries. As less data you load as faster will be the response. Bounding box selects are the fastest way to select a subset of the table. Don't forget to have an index on the geometry column though.

The following answer may give you an idea how to write your query: [Why is any pgr_* routing function taking forever based on OSM data in an pgrouting enabled DB](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69722/why-is-any-pgr-routing-function-taking-forever-based-on-osm-data-in-an-pgrouti/69825#69825)